# Oracle "parent key not found" error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Keep getting this error message but cannot figure out what is causing it...

```
CREATE TABLE section (
SectionID number (10),
CourseID number(10),
SectionNumber varchar2(10),
Days varchar2(10),
StartTime DATE,
EndTime DATE,
LocationID number (10),
SeatsAvailable number(3),
Status char(1)
);

ALTER TABLE section 
Add CONSTRAINT Student_SectionID_pk 
Primary KEY (SectionID);

ALTER TABLE section
ADD CONSTRAINT section_seatsvaiable_cc
Check (SeatsAvailable < 100);

ALTER TABLE section
Add CONSTRAINT section_CourseID_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (courseid)
references course (courseid);


ALTER TABLE section
Add CONSTRAINT section_LocationID_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (locationid)
references location (locationid);

INSERT INTO SECTION ( sectionid, courseid, SectionNumber, Days, Starttime, endtime, locationid, SeatsAvailable, Status) 
VALUES (1, 99, 'B1-H', 'Tue', '22-MAY-13', '3-AUG-13', 29999, 23, 'A');
```

> error at line 1:
>
> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ECOOPER.SECTION_LOCATIONID_FK)
>   violated - parent key not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A location record with ID 29999 doesn't exist in the table `location`.

So your insert doesn't succeed because it doesn't pass all constraints.